# How to print out all the text information from an html-file with lxml parsing?

Tags: python, parsing, iteration, output, lxml

I have an html-file of this kind:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <p>
       <dfn>Definition</dfn>sometext / ''
       (<i>othertext</i>)someothertext / ''
       (<i>...</i>)
       (<i>...</i>)
      </p>
       <p>
         <dfn>Definition2</dfn>sometext / ''
         (<i>othertext</i>)someothertext / ''
         <i>blabla</i>
         <i>bubu</i>
       </p>
     </body>
</html>
```

sometext / ' ' means that there can or cannot be some text following the dfn tag,  same for i tags. also, i tags and text within them are not always present. Only text inside dfn tag is constantly present.

I need to get the following output for every p tag:

> Definition, sometext, othertext, someothertext.
>
> Definition2, sometext, othertext, someothertext, blabla, bubu.

I tried to achieve it with the following code:

```
tree = etree.parse(filename)
places = []
for dfn in tree.getiterator('dfn'):
   def_text = dfn.text
   def_tail = dfn.tail
   for sibling in dfn.itersiblings():   
            sib_text = sibling.text
            sib_tail = sibling.tail
            if def_text not in places:
                places.append(def_text)
                if def_tail == None or sib_text == None or sib_tail == None:
                  continue
                else:
                  places.append(def_tail), places.append(sib_text), places.append(sib_tail) 
return places
```

This gives me output which is half-correct. For example, it just skips the entry of this form:

```
<p><dfn>Cityname</dfn>, text 2349 </p>
```

Or I get text from i-tags and their tags partially...
I suppose that the problem is about iteration, but I can't really find the mistake....

Is there any efficient way to achieve my goal?

P.S. I also tried some things with *tree.xpath('//p/text()')*, but its too general, in my case, I need to extract dfn's siblings' text with respect to dfn itself: if dfn is good(I have some more code to define if dfn is good), then print out dfn and all the text coming with it inside the p tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like the following:

```
for p in tree.xpath("//p"):  # This gets all the p elements
    dfn = p.xpath('./dfn')[0]  # may want to check this exists first
    after_dfn = p.xpath("./dfn/following-sibling::node()")
    for x in after_dfn:
        pass  # do whatever you need to do with the stuff after dfn
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the hint, I have this giving me quite what I need:

```
for p in tree.xpath("//p"):
  dfn = p.xpath('./dfn/text()')
  after_dfn = p.xpath("./dfn/following::text()")
  if dfn!=None:
    print dfn
  if after_dfn !=None:    
    for x in after_dfn:
        print x
```

The only problem is - it results in an infinite loop, how can I get out of it?